# Combining UITableView inserts/moves/deletes with reloadData + custom separators?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which draws its own separator. The cell can be panned to reveal an overflow menu, and the separator animates at that point. Also, the first and last cells in the table have special separators.

Until this point, I've been using `reloadData` to ensure that if a cell was moved to the top, it gets the special separator, and the cell that moved lost that separator, etc.

Now, I want to use `beginUpdates` / `endUpdates` to do some inserts, moves, and deletes in the same `UITableView`, and animate them. This works fine, but I need to remove the `reloadData` call in order for the insert / move / delete animations to work smoothly.

So, I'm in a situation now where I can either have smooth animations, or updating separators in my cells. I'm not quite sure how I can merge the two approaches – anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you update the separators as part of your move/insert/delete operations?

Comment: It's possible, but it's inconvenient. I've written a `UITableView` category to handle animating changes from one data source to another, and in order to update the separators there I'd need to feed all of the custom cells into that category, etc., it'd get messy. It is a viable approach and it may end up being the only possible one, but I'm just wondering if there are neater ways.